# I don't see "additional permissions" for my facebook app

Tags: facebook

Argg. I have a website, with Facebook connect on it. When a user submits a form they're given the option to submit to Facebook.

I have a Facebook application set up. When a user publishes it works fine. If a user decrees that my application cannot publish to Facebook anymore, then it throws an error.

Where do I tell users to go to reauthorize my application? I thought that the flow was:

Application Settings
Click on Edit Settings
Fiddle with Additional Permissions

But I don't see any additional permissions in my app profile. Is there somewhere I need to enable this option? All I see is the option to bookmark it.

Answer (score 0):

You request the permission again (see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication for details on how you can do this)